# What are "levels" and "keyframe distance" when rendering video in Adobe Premiere Levels?

Tags: video-encoding, adobe-premiere

I would like to know what the render option called *Levels* is. Why should I change that to 5.1 or 1.0? What are those levels and how do they affect the final file (size, quality)? All the info I read on the internet, I cannot understand.

Besides that, what does the *Set Keyframe Distance* option on Adobe Premiere do? It is related to I-frames, isn't it? But what is that?

Answer (score 3):

Levels are (agreed upon) constraints put on an encoder. They limit the encoder to certain frame sizes and bit rates in order to make sure that a decoder can correctly decode such a bitstream. This means that a decoder that claims to be compatible with level *X* bitstreams must be able to decode a stream encoded with level *X*. You can find an overview of all [H.264 levels on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264#Levels).

If you do not know what level you need, you should think about your target application. Is it going to be a high definition broadcast or a small video for web? Look at the maximum supported frame dimensions (e.g. 1920×1080 vs 320×240) and frame rates (e.g. 60 Hz vs. 15 Hz) and set the appropriate level.

The level *itself* does not influence the quality or file size. It only enforces a certain upper boundary or gives you a general hint, since logically, a 1080p60 video will be larger than a 320×240 web clip. But generally, you control the quality by setting an average bitrate, or a constant quality level. The level is just secondary here.

---

The keyframe distance doesn't have anything to do with the above. It is the distance (in pictures) between two I-pictures. There are three [types of pictures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-frame) in video compression:

- I-pictures, which can be decoded without reference to others ("intra-coded").
- P-pictures, which can only be decoded with the information from one or multiple previous P- or I-pictures ("previous" as in display order, P standing for "predicted").
- B-pictures, which can only be decoded with the information from one or multiple previous P- or I-pictures ("previous" as in decoding order, not necessarily display order; B standing for "bidirective").

[image]

Here, the P-frame requires the previous I-frame to be decoded first. The B-frame requires the previous P-frame and the following I-frame to be decoded.

The specific implementation of the picture types depends on the codec. The Wikipedia article on [Group of Pictures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures) (GOP) also explains that concept from a different perspective: Usually, I-pictures are interleaved with P- and B-pictures, and occur in a fixed interval—the keyframe interval. This is also the GOP length.

A video with only I-pictures will provide the best quality at the highest file size. The longer the GOP gets, the smaller the file will be, since P-pictures or B-pictures require less bits to encode. Longer GOPs are rarely used for streaming, as a lost frame [might deteriorate the quality](http://psrcentre.org/images/extraimages/113091.pdf), but in broadcasting, a longer GOP is not unusual.

<sub>For a very detailed description of what the picture types mean in H.264, you can also read [Overview of the H.264/AVC Video Coding Standard](http://ip.hhi.de/imagecom_G1/assets/pdfs/csvt_overview_0305.pdf) by Thomas Wiegand et al (see chapter IV A).</sub>